# How to know if a user has changed tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `Tab Bar Controller` which has some `Navigation Controllers` as children. Is it possible to find out when a user navigated away from certain `Navigation Controller` (as he switched to another tab) in form of a callback?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87016/swift-ios-call-back-functions here's a good explanation for callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever class is the Tab Bar Controller's delegate will get sent the following selectors:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```